# Black Screen with two videos using ExoPlayer2

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to implement a small video gallery using ExoPlayer2, I have not trouble with the first couple of videos, but.. When I have played three or four videos, I have a black screen with the next error:

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Playback error.com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, null, -1, null, [1900, 1200, -1.0], [-1, -1])
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:479)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.reinitializeCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1261)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1111)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:552)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:647)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:536)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:303)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

I found a lot of similiar issues with the same error at GitHub's project page with the solution, but no one resolve my problem. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to stop the ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance in all cases (onResume, onPause, onStop), and it works with me.[see the way in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjjio.png)